# In F#, how to correctly use ResizeArray() and an accumulator in an Array.map to change the property of a record

Tags: arrays, f#

(Newbie question). Simple question.

In C#, I have the following code:

```
double openspace = (WorkArea.Width - totalcolumnwidth) / (ColumnCount - 1);

double left = WorkArea.Left;

for (int k = 0; k < ColumnCount; k++)
{
    Cursor cursor = new Cursor
                        {
                            TopLeft = new Point(left, WorkArea.Top),
                        };
    cursors.Add(cursor);
    left += Columns[k] + openspace;
}
```

In F#, I've tried this for simplicity but it fails.

```
type Cursor = { TopLeft: float }

let columnCount = 5.0   // // columnCount number of cursors in List<Cursor> 

let cursors = new ResizeArray<Cursor>(columnCount)   

let mutable left = 20.0

cursors |> Array.map ( fun k -> left <- left + 10 + k.TopLeft ; {k with TopLeft = left} )
```

The goal here is to calculate a new TopLeft value for each Cursor in the cursors array based on an accumalator in 'left' and return a new cursors array with each cursor record having its new value.

How is this done correctly? Can it be done without using a mutable "left" variable?

Thank you in advance.

#Addendum: The "columns" is defined as an array of integers (each integer representing the width of a column).

```
 columns = [|210; 330|]
```

Comment: Types are very import in F# . columncount should be a int. ResizeArray and Array are not the same type. Also it is worth looking into fold.

Comment: You can learn a lot of F# on the site [F# for fun and profit](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/)

Comment: @user1981 Doesn't fold essentially in some form put together the elements of the array? I need a one-to-one approach where each input cursor is updated to a new TopLeft value based on the previous cursor's value.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need a fold (or, to be more precise, a [scan](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-collections-seqmodule.html#scan)) to handle this, because the current `TopLeft` value can actually be computed without reference to the previous `TopLeft` value. This is a good case for an array comprehension. Something like this:

```
    let cursors =
        [|
            for i = 0 to columnCount-1 do
                yield { TopLeft = initialOffset + (columnOffset * float i) }
        |]
```

This works because the columns are constant-width. For variable-width columns, you would definitely need a scan, like this:

```
let columnWidths = [| 210; 340; 200; 300 |]
let initialOffset = 100   // left coord of first column
let columnOffset = 20     // gap between columns
let columnLefts =
    (initialOffset, columnWidths)
        ||> Seq.scan (fun acc width ->
            acc + width + columnOffset)
        |> Seq.take columnWidths.Length   // ignore final value
        |> Seq.toArray
printfn "%A" columnLefts
```

The output is: `100,330,690,910`

Comment: I like this approach. However, in the full case the "columns" each WILL have different widths. More exactly, columns = [|210; 340|].  Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I’ll update my answer later today to show you how to do this with a scan.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to solve this problem with a scan.

Comment: Great! That is exactly what I needed. The documentation on "scan" did not help me much. This does. Thanks.

Comment: Happy to help out. I agree that the doc is weak on this one.